# How to find depth of each dictionary value and comapre them to passed variable

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, nested

This is my dict:

```
{
  "queued": {"failed":{}, "undelivered":{"delivered":{}}}
        }
```

Output should be:

- queued 0
- failed 1
- undelivered 1
- delivered 2

Code I'm using as of now (from other stack question which is **not a duplicate**):

```
def print_depth(our_dict, i=0, target_status):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            i+=1
            print_depth(value, i, target_status)
```

this gets me the output:

- queue 0
- failed 1
- undelivered 2
- delivered 3

You might also wonder what is "target_status". That is a string that should be compared to keys of dict and when found, it should return "i" which is a depth value for a given key. Thanks

Comment: `(our_dict, i=0, target_status)` not correct if you posting code run before posting

Comment: Your function never actually prints anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're incrementing `i` each time through the loop. You should only increment it once for the recursive call. Do that by passing `i+1` as the argument, rather than reassigning the local variable.

```
def print_depth(our_dict, depth=0, target_status = ""):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(f"{key} {depth}")
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print_depth(value, depth+1, target_status)
```

You also can't have positional arguments after optional arguments, so I've added a default value to `target_status`. And I added a `print()` line.

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = {
  "queued": {"failed":{}, "undelivered":{"delivered":{}}}
        }

def print_depth(dic, i=0):
    if isinstance(dic, dict):
        for k in dic:
            print(f'{k}-->{i}')
            print_depth(dic[k], i+1)
            
print_depth(d)
# queued-->0
# failed-->1
# undelivered-->1
# delivered-->2
```